# Should I ask one question or several?

Tags: discussion, multiple-questions-per-post

I have multiple questions for a spell. The questions cover:

- Duration of the spell
- Targets of the spell
- Effects of the spell
- After-effects of the spell once it has worn off

Would it make more sense to ask a separate question for each, or to ask one question that touches on all 4 topics? The answer would apply to multiple spells.

Comment: which game? What's your specific problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: D&D 5th edition. I find parts of the spell ambiguous and I'm wondering if there's any rules that I missed that cover the ambiguity. The PHB doesn't always group all relevant rules together.

Comment: I recommend heading to chat to workshop your question.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a right answer to this question.

If all of the details of the question are interrelated, then you're in good shape to ask it as one question.

However, if this is 4 *general* questions with one spell as the impetus, it should be four.

As [Brian says](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4924/should-i-ask-one-question-or-several#comment11758_4924), if you've got something you're having this much trouble with, there's a really good chance that a quick session in chat can either get you the answers you need, or at least get you to a focused question.