# I have multiple questions about the Slow spell in D&D 5e. Should this be one post, or two?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, questions, multiple-questions-per-post

Should this be one post or two posts?

Several questions about the Slow spell. For reference the relevant parts:

> An affected target’s speed is halved, it takes a -2 penalty to AC and Dexterity saving throws, and it can’t use reactions. On its turn, it can use either an action or a bonus action, not both. Regardless of the creature’s abilities or magic items, it can’t make more than one melee or ranged attack during its turn.
>
> If the creature attempts to cast a spell with a casting time of 1 action, roll a d20. On an 11 or higher, the spell doesn’t take effect until the creature’s next turn, and the creature must use its action on that turn to complete the spell. If it can’t, the spell is wasted.

1. A fighter is affected by Slow. Can they use Action Surge for two actions (attacks) in a turn?

   Action Surge - Starting at 2nd level, you can push yourself beyond your normal limits for a moment. On your turn, you can take one additional action.
2. A sorcerer affected by Slow cast a spell with the Quicken metamagic. Does it always take affect that turn?

   Quickened Spell - When you cast a spell that has a casting time of 1 action, you can spend 2 sorcery points to change the casting time to 1 bonus action for this casting.

Comment: Rather than making a new Meta post to ask the same thing, I would have instead suggested editing [your original post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11808/33569) to include the information from this one. ...That said, there are already a few good answers to that post addressing the general case (and noting that the answer can vary depending on how closely related your questions are); such an edit at this point might end up invalidating those answers, so it might be better to leave these Meta posts separate. (I'll leave that for the community to determine.)

Comment: @V2Blast I strongly vote to keep the other one about the general one and maybe work from there for some kind of easier graspable FAQ?

Answer (score 16):

#### Two separate questions.

You are asking how the spell *slow* interacts with two totally different features from different classes, that do different things, and I can't really see that there is any overlap in how those features work.

*These are good questions*, and I can't find any duplicates on the site.